# For in range loop in python. adding digits together in the strings, inside of a range, then adding that total

Tags: python-3.x, range, for-in-loop

so i have this:

```
def main():
    num = input("Enter a number:")
    total = 0
    for digit in str(num):
        total += int(digit)
    print(total)
main()
```

what this does, is take the digits in a string and add them together (321 would have an output of 6). What i need to do, is do a for in range loop that takes all of the number in the range, take their digits, and add the sum to a whole new total. Basically doing what the first function does but with multiple numbers (for example, entering 10 and 15 would add together 1(10: 1 + 0), 2(11: 1+1), 3(12: 1+2), 4(13: 1+3), 5(14: 1+4), and 6 (15: 1+5).
1+2+3+4+5+6=21. So entering 10 and 15 in the range would have an output of 21.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.

```
def digitSum(x):
    return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x)):

print sum(digitSum(x) for x in range(10,15))
```

or a one-liner:

```
print sum(sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x)) for x in range(10,15))
```

Otherwise, you can modify your existing code to reuse your main function. Here it simply adds up 10 inputs, but you can also have some stopping condition as well:

```
def digitSum(num):
    total = 0
    for digit in str(num):
        total += int(digit)
    return total

def sumOfSums(n1, n2):
    total = 0
    for num in range(n1, n2+1):
        total += digitSum(num)
    return total

def main():
    n1 = input("Enter the first number in range: ")
    n2 = input("Enter the last number in range: ")
    print sumOfSums(int(n1), int(n2))

main()
```

Short variant (making loops flat, that is, in one line is a great feature of Python, and it is not only an aesthetic thing, but I suppose you'll learn it later):

```
n1 = input("Enter the first number in range: ")
n2 = input("Enter the last number in range: ")
print sum(sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x)) for x in range(int(n1), int(n2)))
```

Comment: right, that would work, but i have to work with 2 variables instead of just "num" because it would be collecting a starting and ending number for the range. That's what i'm stuck at.

Comment: OK, so, you don't need to input the numbers to sum up, but the first and last number, right?

Comment: Let me just put the question here(5e is the program i wrote already)
 You will write a complete program which will get two integer inputs from the user, the starting number and the ending number.  You will count from the starting number to the ending number (using a for in range loop), adding the total of each numbers digit count (use the function from assignment 5e).  You will print the digit total after counting.

Comment: Sample Output:

Enter your starting number:10

Enter your ending number: 15

You're digit total is: 21

 

Here is how it calculated:

10 = 1 + 0 = 1

11 = 1 + 1 = 2

12 = 1 + 2 = 3

13 = 1 + 3 = 4

14 = 1 + 4 = 5

15 = 1 + 5 = 6

total = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21

Comment: Please see the edit. Should work now... Would be three lines of code with first variant I showed though :)

Comment: Got a type error, but all i had to do was some casting to int on the input and it worked great! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for

```
def main():
    num1 = str(input("Enter a number:"))
    num2=str(input("Ebter another number:  "))
    numbers=""
    total=0
    if int(num2)-int(num1)>=0:
        for i in range(int(num1),int(num2)+1):
          numbers+=str(i)

    elif int(num2)-int(num1) <0:
     for i in range(int(num2),int(num1)+1):
      numbers+=str(i)

    for digit in numbers:
        total += int(digit)
    print(total)

main()
```

So what you do is that you get two numbers from the user, then you concatenate both numbers and the ones between them in the variable `numbers`. But to get the numbers between them, you have to work out which is bigger to do the `for i in range()` loop.After that it should be self explanatory- I just loop through the string number and convert every element inside it to an integer and add total by that amount.